Visual Studio Code - Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal - Output format
I recently switched from PyCharm to Visual Studio Code. In PyCharm, I'm used to see the following when I run a code selection in the terminal:

In Visual Studio Code however, I get the following result

with "Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal" (it seems that VS Code passes the lines one-by-one to the terminal). This mode is annoying in case I run larger code sections with multiple print statements because the prints are then cluttered and do not appear continuously at the end. I can replicate PyCharms mode by simply copy-pasting the code section into the terminal but this involves a bit more steps. Is there a setting in VS Code so that running "Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal" results in the first image?

I think the functionality you need is similar to this command Run Selection/Line in Interactive Window

It'll open an interactive window and create a new cell then put the selected codes in the cell then run them, which is the same to using jupyter notebook.

